# Add default for missing rows (combinations of students and subjects)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, cross-join

I have a table which holds grades of students in some subjects.

`STUDENT_GRADES`

```
id | studentid | subjectid | grade
-----------------------------------
1  |  1        | 1         | A+
2  |  1        | 2         | A
3  |  1        | 3         | A-
4  |  2        | 2         | A
5  |  2        | 3         | A-
6  |  3        | 2         | B
7  |  4        | 3         | B+
```

and I have another table which holds subject list.

`SUBJECTS`

```
subjectid | subjectname
-----------------------------
1         | Maths     
2         | Science
3         | History
```

Now I have to retrieve result in the following format.

`FORMATTED_GRADES`

```
studentid | subjectid | grade
-----------------------------------
1         | 1         | A+
1         | 2         | A
1         | 3         | A-

2         | 1         | fail
2         | 2         | A
2         | 3         | A-

3         | 1         | fail
3         | 2         | B
3         | 3         | fail

4         | 1         | fail
4         | 2         | fail
4         | 3         | B+
```

The `FORMATTED_GRADES` contains each student from `STUDENT_GRADES` and his/her grade in each subject. If there is no grade of a student in a subject in `STUDENT_GRADES`, then the grade of the student in that subject should be fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate the rows, and `left join` and `coalesce()` to get the data you want:

```
select st.student_id, su.subject_id,
       coalesce(sg.grade, 'fail') as grade
from (select distinct student_id from student_grades) st cross join
     subjects su left join
     student_grades sg
     on sg.student_id = st.student_id and sg.subject_id = su.subject_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You most probably have another table `students` with `studentid` as primary key. Use that in a `CROSS JOIN` to form a Cartesian product with one row for each combination of student and subject:

```
SELECT student_id, subject_id, COALESCE(g.grade, 'fail') AS grade
FROM        students       t
CROSS  JOIN subjects       u
LEFT   JOIN student_grades g USING (student_id, subject_id);
```

**Most importantly**, this includes students that failed in all subjects. If there is no entry in `student_grades` at all, the attempt to distill unique students from `student_grades` ([like @Gordon demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267375/939860)) will miss out on those.

Assuming that `subjects` has no column named `student_id` and `students` has no column `subject_id`. Else you must use the more explicit [join syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) with `ON` instead of the shortcut  with `USING`.

When joining with the `USING` clause, only one instance of the (necessarily identical) join columns is in the output table, hence we do not need table qualification in the `SELECT` list (even if that would be allowed anyway).

Also assuming that `student_grades.grade` is a [character data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html). Else you need to cast explicitly to get compatible data types in `COALESCE`. Like: `COALESCE(g.grade::text, 'fail')`

Comment: Thanks Erwin. This approach gave same output with shorter execution time. +1 for  elaboration.

Comment: @MilanTitaju: Nice. Isn't it the better answer, then?